# Java Spring - annotation @ComponentScan doesn't work scanning controllers package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, annotations

I am trying to make a scanning from a controllers package in my Spring Boot project but the annotation doesn't work.

This is the structure of my project:

[image]

This is my controller (PrincipalController.java)

```
package com.ejemplospring.reuy.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.ejemplospring.reuy.modelo.usuario;

@Component("PrincipalController")
public class PrincipalController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    return "login";
}

@PostMapping("/login")
public String loginForm(Model modelo, usuario usuario){
    String resultado ="";
    if(usuario.getUsuario().isEmpty() || usuario.getContrasena().isEmpty()) {
        resultado = "FALLIDO, ambos campos son obligatorios";
    }else {
        resultado = "Bienvenido usuario!!!";
    }
    
    modelo.addAttribute("resultado",resultado);
    return "menu";
}

}
```

And this is my principal class (HolaUsuarioApplication.java):

```
package com.ejemplospring.reuy.HolaUsuario;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "com.ejemplospring.reuy.controllers")
public class HolaUsuarioApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HolaUsuarioApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

I get the WhiteLabel Error Page.

[image]

It need to automatically go to index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hola index.jsp</h1>
<form action="/login" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="ir a login"/>
</form>
<a href="/login">Ir a Pagina Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried also @ComponentScan("com.ejemplospring.reuy.controllers"), @ComponentScan(value = "com.ejemplospring.reuy.controllers"), @ComponentScan(basePackage = "com.ejemplospring.reuy.controllers") but doesn't work.

Comment: You also need `@Controller`, not `@Component`.

Answer (score 0):

Move HolaUsuarioApplication to “com.ejemplospring.reuy” and remove the @ComponentScan annotation. This will make all the subpackages scanned for components and thus your Controllers will be found.

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Comment: But the main package is com.ejemplospring.reuy.HolaUsuario, why I need to move to another new package (com.ejemplospring.reuy)? I am not able to mantain the same packages but scanning in the controllers package?,

Comment: Or how make the package com.ejemplospring.reuy.HolaUsuario (it contains Holausuario.Java main class), as a main package? or I need to nest the controller package in the main package?

Comment: Because that is the standard way to implement Spring Boot applications and that is why the default of `@ComponentScan` is all subpackages of the class where the annotation is used. `@SpringBootApplication`  encapsulates `@ComponentScan` with the default value. Another thing is that usually `@Controller` is used instead of `@Component` in  Controllers. Nevertheless, why do you say that the annotation does not work? Do you get any error? Additionally, what is ServletInitializer?

Comment: Yes you need to nest it. Main package is the topmost package with classes, in this case it would be only HolaUsuarioApplication.

Comment: Just noticed the issue was elsewhere. Still, you should try to follow Spring Boot development standards so that you avoid nasty issues ;)

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the error was here, in the folder of the JSPs:

[image]

after fix it, works fine.